# Running create role SQL script via Liquibase

Tags: sql, liquibase

I'm trying to create a role in DB using the following SQL statement:

`create role reader_ro;`

The statement runs fine in SQL developer, however it throws the following error when executed via liquibase.

`Error: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option`

I'm injecting the SQL file into the changelog.xml using the  element.

```
<sqlFile encoding="utf8" path="../scripts/file1.sql" relativeToChangeLogFile="true" />
```

Could you please provide any input as to how to approach this issue.

Comment: Read the [docs](https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/liquibase-hub/organizations.html) ?

Comment: By create role, I mean to say running the create role SQL script for a particular DB schema via Liquibase

Comment: Can you show the raw content of the file? 
Are  you sure that the path is correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct, the log displays the SQL statement an then throws the error. The sql File only contains this single statement.

Comment: Another question: Have you verified that the user for which you tested the command is the same as in the luquibase connection string? I'm afraid this problem is just oracle and not Liquibase itself.

Comment: Yes, SQL developer and Liquibase have the same privileges. Can this be a version issue? I'm using liquibase v3.6.3

Comment: Mmm, could be strange. My only advise is to try to have a changeset with a sql tag and embed directly your command. [Here you can find the doc](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/sql.html)

Comment: Yeah, tried that, got the same error :( . I have one question though, the jdbcExecutor which executes the sql queries, which are defined in the changelog.xml file ,comes from liquibase?

Comment: I think that one is implemented in the driver that you set in the Liquibase properties. An idea could be to update it / change it. [From the doc](https://www.liquibase.org/javadoc/liquibase/executor/jvm/JdbcExecutor.html) I can only see the abstract class for it.